# Why not image display as center in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

`UIImageView` doesn't display in center in iOS7 but it display correctly in `StoryBoard` design

Why it coming like that

I'm not using `AutoLayout`

[image]

[Setting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p082I.png)

[image]

[Storyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdJMu.png)

[image]

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzXFl.png).

[image]

see simulator time on the image

Comment: may be it is auto layout issue

Comment: I think you have set autolayout or constraints for imageview and not for your label. Please check..

Comment: Try resetting auto layout constraints

Comment: no i'm not use autolayout

Answer (score 0):

Select both `UIImageView` and `UILabel` and do this in `storyboard`

[image]

and if you are not using auotlayout then you need `AutoSizing` in `XCode` size inspector. Select your `UILabel` and do this-

[image]

Comment: i'm not use autolayout